# Wrap div around other divs with mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I got a main `div` with the class `overview`, in that main div, every 4 elements should be wrapped with a `div`.

Here the html structure:

```
<div class="overview">
    <a class="item" href="#">Test1</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test2</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test3</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test4</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test5</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test6</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test7</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test8</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test9</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test9</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test9</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Test9</a>
</div>
```

How can I do that with mootools?

Answer (score 2):

it's simple, just use mod.

```
(function(){
    var wrapper,
        overview = document.getElement('div.overview');

    overview.getElements('a.item').each(function(a, i){
        if (i % 4 == 0){
            wrapper && overview.adopt(wrapper);
            wrapper = new Element('div');
        }
        wrapper.adopt(a);
    });

    overview.adopt(wrapper);
}());
```

in action: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/4Tana/